# Spark StreamingContext

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a problem running Spark Streaming. Can someone please help me below?

[image: Spark Streaming Error]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using /Filestore, I believe you are using databricks.
Below code would help you to start a spark streaming context.

If you are using databricks, clear all the states and run the below code.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
ssc = StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, 1)
dstream = ssc.textFileStream("<Folder/File location")
dstream.saveAsTextFiles("<Destination folder/file location")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I would suggest you to start using spark structured streaming, instead of using standard streaming option.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html